# SQL (MySQL or MariaDB) problem. How to calculate the number of items in common per category between users

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Here is the SQL challenge / problem (MySQL or MariaDB) that I have to solve.
I managed to solve it however it's not optimal and with a lot of data it will not work well. I'm not very good at SQL.

This is why, not finding other alternatives for the moment, I decide to appeal to collective intelligence.

Presentation: we have users, item categories, items and subitems.
Each item being in a category and a category can have several items (ManyToOne).
Each subitem corresponds to an item and an item can have several subitems (ManyToOne).
And finally, each user can have one or more subitems and each subitem can have one or more users (ManyToMany).
For the ManyToMany relationship between users and subitems, there is a table having as primary key user id and subitem id.

Here is the UML diagram (easier):
[UML Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwr13.png)

**/!\ Warning /!\ Note:** that this design can be completely changed to solve this problem.

Here's the goal:

1. Display the number of subitems in common by category and in total between a given user and the others.

Sample results (here, we display the number of subitems in common with user 1):

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| user_id  | category_1 | category_2 | category_3 | total |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
|     2    |     2      |     3      |     0      |   5   |
|     3    |     0      |     1      |     1      |   2   |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

How do I get this result? Do you have an idea? Another way to do it?
All means are good to solve this, everything MySQL or MariaDB allows (make a different design, use views, temporary tables, stored procedures, virtual columns, etc.).
All ideas are welcome. The goal is to find a solution that can handle a large amount of information.
Thank's a lot in advance, sincerely.

PS: If you want, here is the SQL corresponding to the UML diagram above :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items_categories` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `slug` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `label_UNIQUE` (`label` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `slug_UNIQUE` (`slug` ASC) VISIBLE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `slug` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `items_categories_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `label_UNIQUE` (`label` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `slug_UNIQUE` (`slug` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_items_items_categories_idx` (`items_categories_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_items_items_categories`
    FOREIGN KEY (`items_categories_id`)
    REFERENCES `items_categories` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subitems` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `slug` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `items_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `label_UNIQUE` (`label` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `slug_UNIQUE` (`slug` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_subitems_items1_idx` (`items_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subitems_items1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`items_id`)
    REFERENCES `items` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) VISIBLE);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_has_subitems` (
  `users_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `subitems_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_id`, `subitems_id`),
  INDEX `fk_users_has_subitems_subitems1_idx` (`subitems_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_users_has_subitems_users1_idx` (`users_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_subitems_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_has_subitems_subitems1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`subitems_id`)
    REFERENCES `subitems` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

### Edit :

I've been asked to show my SQL queries, I've done a lot of different ones, but here is the one that gives the result closest to what I need :

I started by creating a view that adds the id categories to the users subitems :

```
CREATE VIEW 'users_has_subitems_categories' AS
SELECT 
    'uhs'.'user_id',
    'uhs'.'subitems_id',
    'ic'.'id' AS 'items_categories_id'
FROM
    ((('users_has_subitems' 'uhs'
    LEFT JOIN 'subitems' 'si' ON (('si'.'id' = 'uhs'.'subitems_id')))
    LEFT JOIN 'items' 'i' ON (('i'.'id' = 'si'.'items_id')))
    LEFT JOIN 'items_categories' 'ic' ON (('ic'.'id' = 'i'.'items_categories_id')))
```

Then I wrote SQL queries allowing me to count the total number of subitems in common for a given user (here user 1). Then the same query with the view to count the total number of subitems for the category and the given user (here category 2, user 1).

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, COUNT(uhs.subitems_id) AS total
FROM 'user'AS u
LEFT JOIN 'users_has_subitems' AS uhs
    ON uhs.user_id = u.id
    AND uhs.subitems_id IN (
        SELECT uhs2.subitems_id FROM 'users_has_subitems' AS uhs2 WHERE uhs2.user_id = 1
    )
WHERE u.id <> 1
GROUP BY u.id;

SELECT u.id AS user_id, COUNT(uhs.subitems_id) AS in_common
FROM 'user'AS u
LEFT JOIN 'users_has_subitems_categories' AS uhs
    ON uhs.user_id = u.id
    AND uhs.items_categories_id = 2
    AND uhs.subitems_id IN (
        SELECT uhs2.subitems_id FROM 'users_has_subitems' AS uhs2 WHERE uhs2.user_id = 1
    )
WHERE u.id <> 1
GROUP BY u.id;
```

Finally I used his SQL queries to join them with the user list.

```
SELECT
    u.id AS user_id,
    uhst1.in_common AS 'category_1',
    uhst2.in_common AS 'category_2',
    uhst3.in_common AS 'category_3',
    uhst.total AS total
FROM 'user' AS u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, COUNT(uhs.subitems_id) AS total
    FROM 'user'AS u
    LEFT JOIN 'users_has_subitems' AS uhs
        ON uhs.user_id = u.id
        AND uhs.subitems_id IN (
            SELECT uhs2.subitems_id FROM 'users_has_subitems' AS uhs2 WHERE uhs2.user_id = 1
        )
    WHERE u.id <> 1
    GROUP BY u.id
) uhst ON uhst.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, COUNT(uhs.subitems_id) AS in_common
    FROM 'user'AS u
    LEFT JOIN 'users_has_subitems_categories' AS uhs
        ON uhs.user_id = u.id
        AND uhs.items_categories_id = 1
        AND uhs.subitems_id IN (
            SELECT uhs2.subitems_id FROM 'users_has_subitems' AS uhs2 WHERE uhs2.user_id = 1
        )
    WHERE u.id <> 1
    GROUP BY u.id
) uhst1 ON uhst1.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, COUNT(uhs.subitems_id) AS in_common
    FROM 'user'AS u
    LEFT JOIN 'users_has_subitems_categories' AS uhs
        ON uhs.user_id = u.id
        AND uhs.items_categories_id = 2
        AND uhs.subitems_id IN (
            SELECT uhs2.subitems_id FROM 'users_has_subitems' AS uhs2 WHERE uhs2.user_id = 1
        )
    WHERE u.id <> 1
    GROUP BY u.id
) uhst2 ON uhst2.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT u.id AS user_id, COUNT(uhs.subitems_id) AS in_common
    FROM 'user'AS u
    LEFT JOIN 'users_has_subitems_categories' AS uhs
        ON uhs.user_id = u.id
        AND uhs.items_categories_id = 3
        AND uhs.subitems_id IN (
            SELECT uhs2.subitems_id FROM 'users_has_subitems' AS uhs2 WHERE uhs2.user_id = 1
        )
    WHERE u.id <> 1
    GROUP BY u.id
) uhst3 ON uhst3.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id <> 1
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This gives me the following results:

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
| user_id  | category_1 | category_2 | category_3 | total |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
|     2    |     2      |     1      |     1      |   4   |
|     5    |     1      |     0      |     1      |   2   |
|     3    |     0      |     0      |     0      |   0   |
|     4    |     0      |     0      |     0      |   0   |
|     6    |     0      |     0      |     0      |   0   |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

But this query has big flaws, already, if you add categories, you have to do it manually in the query (well, with code it's doable) but above all I'm afraid that with many users, subitems, items and categories it becomes very slow.

I'm sure it's possible to do it differently and much better, but even if I ask myself the problem in reverse, I can't get this design out of my head and I'm going around in circles.

I need to be able to rank and return the results in descending order of common subitems in total and/or according to the chosen category as well as to be able to paginate (LIMIT). I'm not going to retrieve the list of all the users in a variable and then do the calculations and then sort and display them, it's unimaginable. There must be another solution, another way? Relational databases are powerful tools for anyone who knows how to use them properly.

Comment: please show us your query

Comment: I added the SQL queries I made to my post. Thank's

Comment: I can't see the INSERTS

Comment: The uml diagram looks ok to me. Maybe you add an extra field to the table 'subitems', in which the 'category_id' is stored. I know, with this we are going to store the 'category_id' twice, but in order to get the desired result, we don't need the 'items' table anymore (one join less). Furthermore you are trying to show a pivot table. Then you should do a pivot query on the raw result set and not mimic the pivot result itself. For this, you should only select the 'user_id' and the 'category_label'. Then make a pivot query on it and you get the result. Not sure whether mysql or mariadb supp. it.

Comment: If no one has an idea how to do this differently, I would like to know how I could optimize things.

With stored procedures, functions, I don't know. There's a way to optimize that.

For the query, I would make an algorithm that will add only the calculated columns I need for the specific case (I don't always need all the columns, sometimes I only need the total).